# react-helmet global styles with :root style block tag in head

Tags: css, reactjs, css-variables, react-helmet

is it possible to add a :root style block with CSS variables to facilitate global styles in react? I've added the following to my layout.tsx page but i get a blank page when it's run (visual studio 2022 react project). if I add a meta tag instead of the style block the meta tag renders on the page so react-helmet is installed and working. I also get an error "(ts) cannot find name --mainThemeF" in visual studio when i hover over the style tag.

Is the layout.tsx the correct place to put this add global styles or is there a better page that may act as a "Master" type page? and Is this even the correct way to add global styles in react as i'm a bit new to it. Thanks.

```
   <React.Fragment>
        <Helmet>
            <style type="text/css">
                :root {
                    --mainThemeF: #ffffff;
                    --mainThemeB: #006633;
                    etc...
                 {
             </style>
         </Helmet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it...boom. It was in the docs, why didn't i just read the docs

```
 <React.Fragment>
        <Helmet>
            <style type="text/css">{`
            :root {
                --mainThemeF: #ffffff;
                --mainThemeB: #006633;                    
             {
         `}</style>
     </Helmet>
```